# Multi Site installation inside a sub domain inside a sub directory

Tags: customization, multisite

I am trying to install multi site inside wordpress installtaion that currently sits in a sub domain and inside a sub directory.

The folder structure / domain structure is as follows:

stage.domain-name.com/wordpress-install

In the install screen its saying the following:

The internet address of your network will be stage.domain-name.com and not stage.domain-name.com/wordpress-install

i want to make sure that it will only affect and install multi site on stage.domain-name.com/wordpress-install and not affect other sub directories As there are other wordpress installations which are currently in stage.domain-name.com/other-wp-sites

would the full multisite url would then be stage.domain-name.com/wordpress-install/multisite ?

Thank You